# Linking data (php) to an accordion container in flash builder

Tags: php, mysql, flash, accordion, builder

I'm building an app where I want to collect various inputs.
An accordion container seems the most efficient method.
The questions and input types needed are all held in a mysql database.
I have a php file with a function which selects all the questions (text).
I have a few different states that each have an accordion container which will ask/collect various amount of questions, all determined by the database.

How (can!) do I bind this to the accordion container so:
- The number of panels produced are equal to the number of questions pulled from the database? (thus dynamic creations of the number of panels based on the database)
- Have the question as the title of the panel?

Any help would be appreciated.
If this isn't possible with Flashbuilder, would going down the path of building my application with java be better? (I would rather not if I could avoid it).

Comment: Do you have any code to share with us?

Comment: I'm not sure what code you would want Sergio? I'm more asking is what I wish to do in Flash Builder possible, and if so, how (link to tutorial would be excellent).